# Add custom object form to Activity of another custom object

Tags: custom-object, lookup, activities

In a custom object, Student, I created the view shows the Activity section with tabs like `New Event`, `New Task`, and `Log a Call`. I have another custom object, `Ticket`, that has an association with Student.

I would like to allow Users to get on and create a Ticket like you would create a Task or Event in the Student's activity section.

Is this possible? Or can I modify the Event/Task objects somehow?

Comment: Yes you can use quick actions here is a link to learn about quick actions https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/salesforce1_mobile_app/salesforce1_mobile_app_actions_objectspecific

Comment: @Ranga Any interest in expanding your comment into an answer, since that is exactly what's needed?

Comment: @DavidReed done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an object specific quick action on Student object and add it to the page layout.

This [trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/salesforce1_mobile_app/salesforce1_mobile_app_actions_objectspecific) explains creating quick actions in detail.

[Here is a link to Salesforce help documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_in_lex.htm&type=5) on quick actions.